# Will the scripts run in JMeter even though the UI is not not as expected?

Tags: jmeter

When I try recording the script through JMeter for my application built on Blazor Technology, none of the contents of the page load.
So I recorded the Scripts through the chrome extension Blazemeter and imported the jmx file to JMeter and ran it.
In the View Results tree response, I see that the requests have failed with Response code:404.
Is this error displayed because the contents of the page do not load when I launch the page through JMeter?
How can I mitigate this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that URL paths you hit don't exist like this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/incorrect/path

or this one:

https://github.com/incorrect/path

More information on HTTP status code 404: [HTTP response status codes
404 Not Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)

In the absolute majority of cases when it comes to modern web applications you cannot just replay the recorded requests because they have some dynamic parameters used for various purposes like [client-side state management](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/) or [security reasons](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens)

So you need to identify all these dynamic parameters, extract them using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), save them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace recorded hard-coded values with the these variables.

The whole process is known as [**correlation**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of material over the web with examples, i.e. you can find [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article useful, it's not about Blazor itself but it about ASP.NET and Blazor is built on top of it, hopefully it will give you some ideas